# Directory / File tree with recursion?

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

Hello I am making a program where a user can drop in either files or folders with files and / or more folders with potentially more files and folders etc

Each of my file objects has a field called above folder name which will store the path of the folders above them. The top folder name is the one they drop first. In future if they add more than one directory at the root level I will handle it but for now you can assume they will only put in one top level folder.

Here is my code so far:

```
 foreach (string fileDropped in files)
        {

            if(Directory.Exists(fileDropped))
            {
                // folder
                string[] filesInFolder = Directory.GetFiles(fileDropped);
                string folderName = fileDropped.Substring(fileDropped.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
                foreach(string fileTemp in filesInFolder)
                {
                    //if this is a directory then do this loop again with recursion?
                    File file = new File(fileTemp);
                    file.aboveFolderName = folderName;
                    dataStorage.AddFileToList(file);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                File file = new File(fileDropped);
                dataStorage.AddFileToList(file);

            }



        }
```

A file multiple layers down would have the entire path from the root folder,

```
"TestFolder/SubTestFolder/SubSubFolder/File.txt"
```

Any suggestions or idea's on how I should structure this?
Thanks

Comment: `foreach (string fileDropped in files) { myMethod(fileDrooped); }` and make `myMethod` recursive when it is a directory. Or use a stack/other data structure manually.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you could do the recursion

```
        public void Recursion(string path, IList<string> paths)
        {
            paths.Add(path);
            if(Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
                paths.Add(directory.FullName);

                foreach (var file in directory.EnumerateFiles())
                {
                    paths.Add(file.FullName);
                }

                foreach (var dir in directory.EnumerateDirectories())
                {
                    Recursion(dir.FullName, paths);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: There's no need to call recursively when enumerating files; you already know that it's not a directory. So when enumerating files, just call `paths.Add`. Come to think of it, no need to check `Directory.Exists` except for the initial call, so that probably should be done before calling the recursive method. Also, no need to make `paths` a `ref`. You're not creating a new collection, but rather just adding things. So remove the `ref`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the overload of `Directory.GetFiles` that searches all sub directories.

```
var allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOptions.AllDirectores)
```

That will return an array of all the absolute paths of all the files in the given path and all sub directories.  You can truncate the paths that are returned like this.

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
foreach(string file in allFiles)
{
    int startOfPath = 0;
    if(dir.Parent != null)
        startOfPath = dir.Parent.FullName.Length + 1;
    File f = new File(file.Substring(startOfPath));
}
```